# Using patch from larger image as input dim to Keras CNN gives error 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'*

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a CNN with keras to process 20x20 patches from a larger image of 600x600.

When I attempt the run the code below I receive an error *AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'*

The below code is only intended to look at the first 20 x 20 patch out of an total of 900, I am trying to get this functioning before attempting to loop through the entire input image.

I don't understand why it is returning the error as each layer is generated with an keras layer and I haven't applied any other operations to the tensor?

I am using tensorflow 1.3 and keras 2.0.6.

```
nb_filters=16

input_image=Input(shape=(600,600,3))
Input_1R=Reshape((900,20,20,3))(input_image)
conv1=Convolution2D(nb_filters,(5,5),activation='relu',padding='valid')(Input_1R[:,0])
conv4=Convolution2D(1,(6,6),activation='hard_sigmoid',padding='same')(conv1)
dense6=Dense(1)(conv4)
output_dense=dense6
model = Model(inputs=input_image, outputs=output_dense)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the slicing operation `Input_1R[:,0]` is not performed in a Keras layer.
You can wrap it into a `Lambda` layer:

```py
sliced = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(Input_1R)
conv1 = Convolution2D(nb_filters, (5,5), activation='relu', padding='valid')(sliced)
```